# How to recover bitcoin wallet from messed up seeds

Tags: blockchain, wallet, wallet-recovery, c#, nbitcoin

I have a ledger nano s wallet that is broken , when i tried to recover wallet from 24 recovery word i got error that says the recovery phrase is incorrect, i think the place of some words is incorrect and one weird thing is one of the words is duplicated in phrase, which i think is wrong.

So far i wrote a program in C# with nbitcoin library that checks all 2048 words of BIP39 wordlist in one place of 24 place and tried to generate its deposit address and compare it to lost wallet address like (i checked the code with new ledger wallet address and it worked) and i couldn't the correct phrase.

Write now i want to generate every possible combinition of these word and check them, i think it's around 24! Possibilities which is almost impossible to check, but i also know that every combinition of words in wordlist is not true and there is a checksum which i hope limit the possibilities.

Right now i need a code preferably in C# with nbitcoin library to generate every possible and true phrases of mnemonic and a suggestion for fast checking the phrase against the wallet.

Comment: i already using btcrecover library, the problem is I don`t know python and I can`t read the source and optimize it to my need

Comment: U probably may need to pay someone to do the program. Please don;t give them your 24 recovery word OK. Otherwise, your $$fund is as good as gone.